# Terraform : Error with Comply with restrictions

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

In terraform , Trying to S3 bucket as trigger to my lambda and giving the permissions. For this use case , creating S3 resource and trying to refer that lambda function in triggering logic. But When I refer code is failing with below error.

```
# Creating Lambda resource


resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  filename      = "output/welcome.zip"
  function_name = var.function_name
  role          = var.role_name
  handler       = var.handler_name
  runtime       = var.run_time
}



# Creating s3 resource for invoking to lambda function



resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "source-bucktet-testing"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "source-bucktet-testing"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}


# Adding S3 bucket as trigger to my lambda and giving the permissions


resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "aws-lambda-trigger" {
  bucket = "aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id"
  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.arn"
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "file-prefix"
    filter_suffix       = "file-extension"
}
}
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "test" {
  statement_id  = "AllowS3Invoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.function_name"
  principal = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = "arn:aws:s3:::aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id"
}
```

Error Message :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value passed to the `aws_lambda_function` resource for `function_name` is invalid. An AWS Lambda function name can only contain letters, numbers, hyphens, or underscores with no spaces. You need to change the value of `var.function_name` to align with these restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. After changing var.function_name also giving the same issue. Error: "function_name" doesn't comply with restrictions ("^(arn:[\\w-]+:lambda:)?([a-z]{2}-(?:[a-z]+-){1,2}\\d{1}:)?(\\d{12}:)?(function:)?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(:(\\$LATEST|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+))?$"): "aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.var.function_name"

  on main.tf line 78, in resource "aws_lambda_permission" "test":
  78:   function_name = "aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.var.function_name"

Comment: This error is because you aren't interpolating the value for the `aws_lambda_permission` resource. You are passing the literal string `"aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.function_name"`, change it to `"${aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.function_name}"` @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj

Comment: now am getting below compatibility issue : 
Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

  on main.tf line 78, in resource "aws_lambda_permission" "test":
  78:   function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.function_name}"

Terraform 0.11 and earlier required all non-constant expressions to be
provided via interpolation syntax, but this pattern is now deprecated. To
silence this warning, remove the "${ sequence from the start and the }"
sequence from the end of this expression, leaving just the inner expression.

Comment: Remove the `"${` and `"` like it recommends, leaving just `aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.function_name`.

Comment: @KarthikeyanRasipalayDurairaj If the answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `var.function_name` must be invalid.

The allowed function name format is explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunction.html#SSS-CreateFunction-request-FunctionName) along with ARN:

```
The length constraint applies only to the full ARN. If you specify only the function name, it is limited to 64 characters in length.

Type: String

Length Constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 140.

Pattern: (arn:(aws[a-zA-Z-]*)?:lambda:)?([a-z]{2}(-gov)?-[a-z]+-\d{1}:)?(\d{12}:)?(function:)?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(:(\$LATEST|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+))?
```

Comment: In that case , How can i declare instead of below statement : unction_name = "aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.var.function_name". can you please suggest me on this .